# Difference between map and dict

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap

I might be confused between `hashmap` in Java, and `map`/`dict` in Python.
I thought that the `hash` (k/v abstraction) of Java is kind of the same as `dict` in Python

But then what does the `map` datatype do?

Is it the same abstraction as the hashmap abstraction? If so, then how is it different from dictionary?
I went through the docs, but it took me to whole together different paradigm: functional programming.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but for Python, this might be the documentation you are looking for: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Comment: To answer the question in the title, it is the same. A map seen as a datastructure is the same concept as a `dict`. `dict`s also use hashes to map keys to values. That's why java developers call it hashmap.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[Map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) is not a datatype in python.  It applies a function to a series of values and returns the result.

```
>>> def f(x):
...     return x**2
... 
>>> list(map(f, range(5)))
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Often for a simple case like that to be "pythonic" we use list comprehensions.

```
>>> [x**2 for x in range(5)]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

You are right in your comparison of hashmaps and dicts.

Comment: As of Python 3, map *is* a datatype -- [see my answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45087342/1048186)

Comment: Thanks @JosiahYoder, I've updated my answer to wrap the `map` call with `list`

Answer (score 8):

In essence a `Map` in Java is like a `dict` in Python: both data structures create associations between keys and values, with expected O(1) performance for the `get()` and `contains()` operations.

The `Map` data structure in Java should not be confused with the [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) function in Python:

> map(function, iterable, ...)
>
> Apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the results. If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel

Comment: "Guaranteed O(1) performance" isn't quite right. See http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `dict` is the Python equivalent of the Java `Map`, `HashMap`, `TreeMap`, etc.

**In Python 3**, `map(...)` returns an iteratable datatype, equivalent to what is returned by itertools's `imap` in Python 2.

To get the same results in Python 3 as [Nolan Royalty's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10066393/1048186) Python 2 example  you would write:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     return x**2
... 
>>> list(map(f, range(5)))

[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

If you don't wrap it in a list in Python 3, you will get a map object:

```
>>> map(f, range(5))
... <map object at 0x000000000327E780>
```

So there **are** map objects, which are iterable, in Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

There is no map data type in python. map is a function that maps a function to an sequence.

```
def increment(n):
    return n+1
l = [1,2,3]
map(increment, l)
```

will give you a new list [2,3,4]